# Giving a process exclusive use of a CPU core on a Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, interrupts

On the quad-core CPU Pi 3, is there a way of giving one single-threaded process exclusive use of a single, named, core?

Interrupts would also need to be routed away from the chosen core.

The purpose is to enable GPIO from the single-threaded process without scheduling or interrupt glitches.  Would this enable deterministic GPIO, assuming the single-threaded process did not need to access main memory?  i.e. it just used registers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure.

You can use sched_setaffinity to limit a process to a single core.  You can also use sched_setaffinity to tell another process not to use that core.

`man sched_setaffinity`

That might get part way to what you want.

You can also tell Linux not to use a core (at least I think there is a `/boot/config.txt` option or it may be a standard Linux boot option in `/boot/cmdline.txt`).

However if Linux isn't using the core how will you execute code on the core?

I've heard of suggestions to use bare metal on the dedicated core.  I don't remember reading of any successful hybrid experiments.